# How can i make timer to counting?

Tags: delphi, timer

I have try with this kind of code but not working, whats the problem ?

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Tag := Timer1.Tag + 1;
  if Timer1.Tag >= 61 then
  begin
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the absorption refrigerator... No, seriously, what does "not working" mean ? Be precise when describing your problems. That it's not working may stand for hundreds of meanings. I'm not a downvoter, but by asking such questions you're exposing yourself to get some.

Comment: As TLama notes, you need to be more specific.  What are trying to accomplish. In what way isn't it working. (By the way, you could set the Timer1's interval to the delay you want to avoid counting at all.)

Comment: @user We would like to help, but your questions are deficient. This is the second time you've essentially asked this question. Both times we've asked for improvements and both times you have not responded. In order for this to work you will need to engage with us.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing 'wrong' with the code... it works fine. However, what are you expecting? A TTimer placed on a TForm will be Enabled by default, so it will start. Its Interval will be 1000 by default, its Tag will be 0 by default. When enabled, this Timer1 will 'count' from 1 to 61 and then disable itself... by 'count' I mean it will change its Tag value... up to 61 before Enabled is set to False.

If that's what you're expecting to happen, then it should be happening.

Comment: -1 This should be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to comment... it said "You must have 50 reputation to comment" when I tried that. I'm not going to get to 50 if you mark it down, am I?

Comment: We all have to start somewhere. You won't get 50 rep by writing comments in answer fields. I'm sorry that you don't have enough rep to comment, but that's just tough. Write some good answers and you'll get upvotes. Pick the right questions to answer. A question like this is a disaster and is best shunned. Impossible to answer.

Comment: Yeah, slow hand-clap for you.

Comment: We are talking about you

Comment: I see you are enjoying yourself. I would point out 2 very brief things - **1**, you suggest the original question is ignored, yet you commented on it yourself - but with nothing helpful at all (whereas I could not comment on it, so I tried to answer it) and **2**, there _is_ a valid question raised by user3267883, it was "what's the problem?" and the answer was "there should be no problem, the code works" with an question / comment added - "is this what you're trying to actually do?" I genuinely reckon my 'answer' was more helpful than your comment.

Comment: This user keeps asking these non-questions. The site policy is that such questions get closed. Non-answers are discouraged too. I don't make the rules. If you don't like how it is you can ask a question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yet you still went to the effort of commenting, just _not_ helping. That is why you fully deserve your slow hand-clap - because you down-voted someone who did the _same thing_ that you did (just better, and with better intentions). The power must really go to _your_ head, ey?

Comment: I did help. The three comments to the question are the help that the asker needs. The asker doesn't need help with his timer. He needs serious help with his ability to ask questions in a clear manner. That's the fundamental issue. Your comments would have been helpful as comments. But they are not an answer. If you have a problem with that, seek clarification on meta. There's no need to be rude.